# compiling a python script using the selenium library

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I compile a python script with this command :

```
pyinstaller --onefile .\tdistrib_comp.py --add-binary "driver\geckodriver.exe;driver\"
```

The executable file is correctly generated but does not work when I double click on it.

```
script of tdistrib_comp.py:
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='./driver/geckodriver.exe')
```

For your information, I'm using python 3.10 on Windows 10. Could you please help me to solve this difficulty?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did something very similar in an old project. I chose to keep the geckodriver as a separate file not add it in the exe as a binary and it worked for me.

Comment: @vladc. with only the command pyinstaller --onefile .\tdistrib_comp.py ?